# Eclipse hangs when installing new software

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install new software within Eclipse the C++ version. `Help -> install new software`. When I go to install new software, it hangs or takes hours to move a percentage.

I have read that this is a known bug in `JRE7`, which I am assuming I am using since I have it installed. I changed to `JRE6` by changing the `eclipse.ini` file with the argument `-vm XXXX` where `XXXX` is the path to my `javaw.exe`.

It does not seem to have changed anything.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally it worked for me only by unchecking **Contact all update sites during install to find required software**. From what I'm seeing it might be a Mac issue, on Windows and Linux it worked without any change.

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of this problem by simply disabling your Firewall software before installing new plugin. If your Antivirus has built-in Firewall, you need to disable it.

Optionally, to reduce the update time, you can uncheck *Contact all update sites during install to find required software*, see [my blog post for details](http://techcetra.blogspot.in/2012/08/eclipse-hangs-while-adding-new-plugin.html).

Comment: "uncheck Contact all update sites during install to find required software" worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I've found it helps by adding this line to the eclipse.ini file:

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Answer (score 0):

To install new plugin into eclipse, you can download plugin installer or go market place to install.
Make sure what SDK you are using and fill the correct path.
Wish you success

Answer (score 0):

To get around this issue, I went to Windows->preferences->general->network settings and typed in each repository manually. I also selected manual from the drop down at the top of the window.

It seems it was also useful to get off of my home network and I had to get on another network.

Answer (score 0):

I kept having this issue and resolved it by following Nitin Kale's fix for Eclipse slowness on fresh 16.04 here> https://askubuntu.com/a/788826

> open terminal and type following command
>
> export SWT_GTK3=0  add this to your ~/.profile file to make it
>   persistent across logins (you'll need to logout and log back in to be
>   able to start eclipse from shortcut)
>
> then go to your eclipse folder and search for eclipse.ini file Right
>   click anywhere in the folder and choose "open in terminal" and type
>   following command in terminal
>
> sudo gedit eclipse.ini   and add the following line before
>   --launcher.appendVmargs
>
> --launcher.GTK_version 2   Search in the file for 256 and replace it with 1024

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to Preferences -> General -> Network Connection and set Active provider to 'direct' as it was 'native' by default. Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

None of above methods worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Eclipse Mars. Had to do following

> Go to "Preferences"->"Install/Update"->"Available Software Sites" and uncheck all except "Mars".

After this install worked in a jiffy.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by following all steps in above answers

1. Window -> Prefrerences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites and then uncheck all except Your package name ( neon, mars ).
2. Window -> Prefrerences -> General -> Network Connections and set Active provider to "manual".
3. Help -> Install new Software -> uncheck "contact all update sites during install".

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this issue simply go to windows defender and add the installation app as an exception.